# Deleting DynamoDB items by simple GSI

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I have an attribute `some_id` on every item in my table. The table has a simple GSI on `some_id`. I want to delete all items with `some_id` equal to some value I provide.

What's the best way to do this? I've seen StackOverflow posts recommend querying by the index and then putting each item in a DeleteItem then combining them in a BatchWriteItem. It seems like the standard method, but each BatchWriteItem holds a max of 25 puts/deletes. So I'm also looking for general code (preferably in Go) that handles all cases, such as looping through the query response if there's more than 25 items as well as handling when there's `UnprocessedItems`.

Comment: I think that's pretty much the solution right there. I'm not aware of any Go code that implements this, but it doesn't sound too challenging.